# Erlang: Convert binary data into a list containing the number of consecutive ones

Tags: binary, erlang

%Question
Say I have a binary number:
1011011101111011111
Each digit is one bit.

I want to be able to transform that into:
[1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111]

...and eventually into:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

%What I tried
I tried binary:split, but data is always encoded in chunks of bits. I just want to work with the raw data (if that is possible.)

%What I am trying to accomplish
I am designing a header for a routing protocol. I want the header to contain a list of addresses that the packet has already visited. I figured I would not have to place any restrictions on the total length of the header if I give the header itself a header that consists of consecutive ones separated by zeros. The header's header would be separated from the header itself by two consecutive zeros. So if I had a payload that said:
 <<"Hello World">>
and the data has been visited by alice, bob, and carl, then header would be:
<<"alicebobcarl">>
and the header's header would be:
(8*5 ones) 0 (8*3 ones) 0 (8*4 ones) 00
assuming we are using some 8 bit encoding for the header.

Then the actual packet would read:
(8*5 ones) 0 (8*3 ones) 0 (8*4 ones) 00 <<"alicebobcarl">> <<"Hello World">>

To decipher the header, I would first locate the first instance of 00, and split everything before that 00 at each 0. Then I would transform the resulting list into a list that contains number of bits in each address the packet had traveled to. Then I can finally read off the addresses from the header and retrieve the payload.

Comment: Two while loops will do it.  The outer one loops until the number becomes 0, the inner one loops while the LSB is 1, and counts the number of times that happens until a 0 is reached.

Comment: I am pretty sure Erlang does not have for/while loops. Besides, I do not know how to actually read off individual bits in Erlang.

Comment: Whoops -- I know nothing about erlang -- maybe my comment isn't helpful. That's how I'd do it in a low-level language like C.

Comment: Erlang has recursion, so it can do loops, and it has division and modulus, so you can read off the LSB and do bit shifts.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(8*5 ones) 0 (8*3 ones) 0 (8*4 ones)`?

Comment: @Ed'ka you are right--I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitstring comprehensions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79375) to the resque:

```
1> Inp = <<1:1,0:1,3:2,0:1,7:3>>.
<<"À">>
2> [ size(B) || B <- binary:split(<< <<I>> || <<I:1>> <= Inp >>, <<0>>, [global]) ].
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. At the time of writing this comment, I have never seen the ||, <- or <= syntax. I have some reading to do!

Comment: My one complaint with this method is that it returns the trailing zeros as part of the list. I want it to stop after 00 and not include the 00 in the result.

Comment: Ok, so I found if you add the trim option, you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Can you convert binary to string?

Suppose you can, then do like following:

```
B = "1011011101111011111",
S = string:tokens(B, "0"),
R = lists:map(fun(E)->length(E) end, S).
```

But this is not efficient. Expect good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can parse header:

```eralng
-module(bitcnt).
-export([parse_header/1]).

parse_header(Message) ->
        parse_header(Message, []).

parse_header(<<0:1, 0:1, Body/bitstring>>, Header) ->
        %% stop if found header delimiter - two consecutive zero bits
        %% return parsed header and message body
        {lists:reverse(Header), Body};
parse_header(<<1:1, Rest/bitstring>>, []) ->
        %% handle if first bit is '1'
        parse_header(Rest, [1]);
parse_header(<<1:1, Rest/bitstring>>, [H | T]) ->
        %% handle consecutive '1' bits of header
        parse_header(Rest, [H+1 | T]);
parse_header(<<0:1, Rest/bitstring>>, Header) ->
        %% handle delimiters inside header - '0' bit
        parse_header(Rest, [0 | Header]).
```

Let test it in shell. Assume such header '10110111' (must be parsed into [1,2,3]) + delimiter '00' + some body <<12345:64>>:

```eralng
2> B1 = <<1:1,0:1,1:1,1:1,0:1,1:1,1:1,1:1,0:1,0:1,12345:64>>.
<<183,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,14,1:2>>
3> 
3> bitcnt:parse_header(B1).
{[1,2,3],<<0,0,0,0,0,0,48,57>>}
4> 
4> <<12345:64>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,48,57>>
```

Another test '11101' (must be parsed into [3,1]) + '00' + <<12345:64>>

```eralng
5> B2 = <<1:1, 1:1, 1:1, 0:1, 1:1, 0:1, 0:1, 12345:64>>.
<<232,0,0,0,0,0,0,96,57:7>>
6> 
6> bitcnt:parse_header(B2).                             
{[3,1],<<0,0,0,0,0,0,48,57>>}
```

Even if header is empty (message starts with two consecutive zero bits) - function parse header into empty list:

```eralng
7> B3 = <<0:1, 0:1, 12345:64>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,12,14,1:2>>
8> 
8> bitcnt:parse_header(B3).    
{[],<<0,0,0,0,0,0,48,57>>}
```

**P.S.**

By the way, **format of your header is very redundant**. If you're want to encode big numbers, for example, number 1024 - you'll need to transform it to 1024 consecutive '1' bits!

**There is two ways to improve format of your header:**

- if you know that any of your numbers is less than some threshold number: calculate how many bits you're need to encode number with maximum value, and **encode each of your numbers in header with bitstring of pre-defined length**. For example - if all of your numbers are less than 2^32 - you need 32 bit to encode each number from this interval
- if you can't define threshold (number with maximum value): **use variable length coding**. For example, [Elias gamma-coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) or [Exponential-Golomb coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential-Golomb_coding).

Comment: I read and reread your answer, then I read about the encoding methods you mentioned. Unless I am misunderstanding, my method does not seem so far from the Elias gamma-coding. In fact, the only reason I would not go with the Elias gamma-coding in this case is that I would have to encode the data too--requiring a list of zeros almost as long as the data. To encode a header that says 1024, I would give the header a header of 10 ones followed by two zeros followed by the binary 1024 header followed by the data.

Comment: That, by the way, would imply that the packet visited a computer called 10000000000 (an odd name indeed).

Comment: @Feynman, So, you encode each number into corresponding consecutive string of `1` bits? `1->1`, `2->11`, `3->111`, `4->1111` ? It is very redundant. It is very far from `Elias gamma coding`.

Comment: @Feynman, For example, in Elias gamma coding number `16` would be represented as `000010000` (9 bits). But if encode `16` with your algorithm it would be represented as `1111111111111111` (16 bits)

Comment: @Feynman, But if you don't care about redundancy - look the function `parse_header` from my answer, it implements your algorithm

Comment: nothing in the header's header is really supposed to be recognized as a number. It is just a way of determining how long each part of the header is. The zeros are like commas. The double zero at the end means "stop header's header, begin header itself." The header is not recognized as a number, it is recognized as a series of binaries that are not separated by any delimiters. If the header was 1024 in binary: 10000000000, the header's header would be: 111111111100 which is 12 bits for the header's header. Followed by a 10 bit header = 22 bits total.

Comment: The Elias gamma coding for 1024 would be 00000000010000000000, which is 20 bits. See? I am not so far off!

Comment: As of now, I evaluating all the answers I have gotten along with possible ways of improving upon them so I can choose the answer I think is most efficient while staying within the bounds of the problem. Since asking this question, I managed to hack the as_bits function here: http://erldocs.com/R14Aextra/lib/elib1_misc.html, so I am also checking to see if any of the answers here are more efficient than the way I have currently com up with.

Comment: @Feynman, There is no profit from inventing own bicycles, especially if exists better solutions. You see that existing algorithms of variable length coding are still better. Also, important moment - existing algorithms of variable encoding doesn't need delimiters at all. But I'll be happy to stop this unconstructive discussion